# Delay between two instantiations of same module

Tags: verilog

I want to run the following code:

```
module a (input a1 ,clock, reset, output aout);

----
----
----

key k1(a1,clock,reset,k1out); // it takes around 40 cycles to complete 

key k2(k1out,clock,reset,k2out);

endmodule
```

`k1out` is displayed correctly, but `k2out` is not. In fact I am getting `k2out` as *xxxxx*. Is there any way to provide delay between these two instantiations so that they get executed in order and I can get the output correctly?

Comment: @Morgan  Thank you for the reply. Can you please elaborate about how to control the clock please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your describing hardware, those two instances exist in parallel.

You could either control the clock to each block so the execute sequentially, or build a state machine to sequence them.

With clock gating (internal to key):

```
module a (input a1 ,clock, reset, output aout);

----
----
----

logic [6:0] state;
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    state <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    if (state >= 7'd80) begin
      state <= 'b0 ;
    end else 
      state <= state + 1'b1;
  end
end

wire k1_enable = (state <  7'd40 );
wire k2_enable = (state >= 7'd40);


key k1(a1,   clock,reset,k1out, k1_enable); 
key k2(k1out,clock,reset,k2out, k2_enable);

endmodule
```

Sequential elements of key now use:

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    data <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    if (enable) begin
      data <= ; //next value
    end
    //else hold data
  end
end
```